# GCM to get push notifications if I Force stop the app

Tags: android

I have used GCM to get push notifications, now if I Force stop the app from the settings on the Android device, will it be able to get push notifications without restart application...

Comment: thank for reply Mr. MD ....but my problem is how we can restart notification without open the application progamtically...please reply

Comment: **restart notification** ??? What are you talkin about??

Comment: Once you force stop your app, you wont be able to receive any notification, its just like app being uninstalled from device.

Comment: Mr.Techfist   In facebook aur many other application we recived Notification without restart that application...i have seen that many application use WakefulBroadcastReceiver keyword for send Gcm notification ....can you plz tell me what is use of this key word in GCM??

Comment: @ Md ...In facebook ,what's app aur many other application we recived Notification without restart that application...i have seen that many application use WakefulBroadcastReceiver keyword for send Gcm notification ....can you plz tell me what is use of this key word in GCM??

Answer (score 0):

No. If the user force-stops your app, they are indicating that they do not want your app to run again, for any reason, until they manually launch it again. Your objective is to give the user no reason to force-stop your app. Note that I do mean "force-stop" (i.e., press the "Force Stop" button from Settings) -- ordinary task managers, or swiping from the Recent Tasks list in Android 4.x, does not have this effect.